# On Cell change event vba for Zero or Blank values

Tags: vba, excel

I m trying to get hold of on cell change event vba code, if the cell value is changed to blank or zero. otherwise i have code which triggers if the cell value is updated to either more than or less than zero.

I understand that excel by default assumes blank cells to be zero but as part of a task i need to capture the cell, if value is changed to zero or blank.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something in your question, this should be as simple as:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In Target.Cells
        If Len(cell.Text) = 0 Or cell.Value2 = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Captured " & cell.Address
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```